# Dynamically import file

Tags: python, file, import, reload

I'm writing a little script that transforms the output files of one program into the input files of another one.

To create these input files some additional user input is required.
I want to have this user input in a separate file. When running the script the user can specify his configuration file via `sys.argv` as a string.

The configuration file only contains variables, not functions:

```
N_a = 2
N_b = 5
N_c = ...
 .
 .
 .
```

What is now the best practice to import the variables in a file given by a string?
And most important: This file should be reloaded every time the script is executed in case the user changed something in between two runs. Is it possible to do this for every arbitrary file or does it need to be a `.py` file?

Comment: Have you considered using the `configparser` module ? You can create a config file using the syntax described in the module and use it to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you can use `eval` to take an arbitrary string and evaluate it as python code. Alternatively, you can use `exec` to execute an arbitrary string as a python expression.

In general, it is **not recommended** to do this, as it makes your program vulnerable - imagine that someone knew your code was using this `eval` or `exec` function, a malicious user could insert some python code into their config file and do some real damage do your system.

Rather, I think what you want to do is parse the user's config file and set variables appropriately. For example:

```
# file configParser.py
userfile = 'users_file.txt'
values = {}
with open(userfile, 'r') as infile:
    for line in userfile:
        name, value = line.strip().split('=')
        values[name] = value
```

You can then later use the `values` dict to access these values:

```
values['N_a'] # holds '2'
values['N_b'] # holds '5'
# etc...
```

Note that the values stored are strings. You can convert them to `int`s or `float`s or w/e as you want.

Something to keep in mind is that this approach assumes ever line consists of a `variable_name = value` pattern. If the user deviates from this pattern or happens to provide an invalid value, the parser will likely crash. There are modules such as `configparser` that are purpose-built to allow you to specify a config-file format that the user can use to provide data to your program.

Comment: great answer :) ++ to the configparser recomendation

Answer (score 1):

the safest would be to manually parse the file ...

but you could certainly use

```
execfile("/path/to/a.py")
```

although.. and yes its ending can be whatever you want .conf, .blah ,...